# Can kafka function like pubsub by dynamically create consumergroup on demand?

Tags: apache-kafka, publish-subscribe

If you have tens of thousands of consumer each needing its own copy of latest message, and consumer number fluctuates by going in and out constantly, can kafka support this usecase?

The only way I can think of is to dynamically register a new consumer group every time a new consumer (device, server) need it, and destroy the consumer group every time an existing consumer (device, server) don't need it, and have a service that regularly check if there is any consumergroup not being used and delete them

When a consumer group is created in kafka, the overhead is just a pointer to the message log, can kafka scale ten of thousands of consumer group if not millions

Or is this a bad use case for kafka and we should be using any alternative instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're only required to use consumer groups to commit offsets and scale out consumers. (and Kafka automatically deletes "unused" groups, or those that have had no offsets committed in some time)

If you have single "devices" that are unique, there's no reason for creating a "group", especially if you only need "the latest message"

Though, if you are in an IOT environment, then MQTT is typically used in connection with Kafka or NATS

Comment: if I have 2 device, same consumer group will cause each message to go to one device and not both, I need each device in its own consumer group to receive a copy of each message

Comment: Only if you've got one partition in that topic. You're never required to use groups. Use assign function on every device and track offsets manually.